# Modelar comentários

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Estou criando uma estrutura de comentários semelhante a do [MercadoLivre](http://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/MLB-681216137-celular-smartphone-3g-wi-fi-tela-de-5-android-43-dual-_JM#D[S:HOME,L:RECOMITEM-CORE-UNO-BEST-DEAL,V:1]), como faço para que a modelagem contemple e garanta que:

OBS: estou chamando comentários de pergunta e resposta já que é basicamente desta forma que o modelo do Mercado Livre funciona.

Em vermelho perguntas e em verde as respostas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1. Haja somente um nível de resposta para determinada pergunta.
2. Uma pergunta ter varias respostas.
3. Uma resposta para uma unica pergunta.
4. Nenhuma pergunta para uma resposta.
5. Perguntas e resposta para um único produto.
6. Ser possivel ser redirecionado ao comentário como aqui no SOpt (**pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78765/problemas-com-post-em-angularjs/78773?noredirect=1#comment173023_78773**)

O que já fiz:

```
comments
--------

id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
comment_text VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,,
type INT NOT NULL,
user_id INT NOT NULL, #chave estrangeira para usuário que postou o comentario.
product_id INT NOT NULL, #chave estrangeira para o produto a qual os comentários se referem.
posted_to INT #fiquei com dúvida porque uma resposta é postada para uma pergunta mas uma pergunta não é postada para ninguém.
date_posted DATE
```

Comment: Que informação vai ser gravada em `posted_to`? Tem alguma dúvida específica? Se eu entendi parece estar tudo certo. Algumas destas regras obviamente serão garantidas no código e não na modelagem.

Comment: seria um inteiro para o id do produto ou pergunta

Comment: Então o que você quer saber? Se está tudo certo?

Comment: @bigown gostaria que minha modelagem abrange-se os 6 pontos citados na pergunta e sanar minhas dúvidas que postei na modelagem (é possível que surjam outras assim que sane estas)

Comment: O item 4 não entendi bem, alguém poderia simplesmente postar uma resposta sobre algo que não foi perguntado, é isso? O item 6 depende da aplicação a ser desenvolvida e não à modelagem do banco de dados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece estar tudo certo de acordo com as informações fornecidas. Claro que as regras do que pode ou não fazer, de como apresentar (incluindo *links*), será determinado pelo código (ainda que dentro do banco de dados, o que não me agrada) e não pela modelagem.

Eu só usaria um `NULL` (parece que ele foi preparado para isto) ou valor 0 em `posted_to` quando por uma pergunta. Não tem porque duplicar nesta coluna a informação que já está no `product_id`.

E se eu entendi o que é o `type`, **talvez**, ele nem seja necessário, porque dá para inferir pelo conteúdo de `posted_to`. Mas não sei se vale fazer esta economia, até porque no futuro pode mudar alguma coisa e isto não ser mais possível. Claro que teria como resolver o problema facilmente **se** for necessário. Podemos pensar em [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) aqui, ou não tentar ser muito [*clever*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/25276/389) (o problema é decidir o que é *clever* demais).

Um `date_posted` ser `NOT NULL` parece ser adequado também.

Aí poderia pensar em outras coisas que não estão contempladas nessa análise básica. Por exemplo: a possibilidade do comentário ser removido (mas mantê-lo no banco de dados) exigira uma coluna para indicar o estado.

Comment: 1º ter vários posted_to com NULL ou 0 consumiria memoria ainda? 2º se remover o product_id como saberei a qual produto pergunta/resposta referenciam?

Comment: Sim mas isto não é importante. Em muitos banco de dados o `NULL` pode consumir menos mas é pouco relevante. Existem SGDBs que ele não consome nada mas na verdade é porque já consome em excesso de outra forma. Nem sei se algum *mainstrem* hoje faz isto. E se fizer, novamente não importa. Eu não falei para remover nada no `product_id`, falei para não repetir ele em `posted_ to` quando for uma pergunta. E falei que o `type` é uma informação redundante na forma atual (e não necessariamente isto é ruim), e se eu entendi para que ele serve.

Comment: Acho melhor você ler de novo a resposta, eu não falei em `NULL` no `product_ id`. Eu falei em `posted_ to`.

Comment: Equivoquei-me em meu comentário gostaria de perguntar se deixo o product_id com NULL quando for uma resposta e posted_to com NULL quando for uma pergunta

Comment: Ah, sim, pode até fazer isto, mas eu não faria, porque pode dificultar as consultas. Hipoteticamente poderia fundir as duas colunas em uma só e a coluna `type ` definir se ali tem um `id` de produto ou de pergunta. Mas seria *clever* demais, não é necessário e dificultaria ainda mais as consultas. Este tipo de coisa é o que se fazia nos anos 60/70 quando tinha muita restrição de recursos. E olha no que deu, o tal do *bug do milênio*.

Comment: Bom esclarecimento +25

Comment: bigown se optar pela opção _clever_ eu não conseguirei fazer com que o campo `posted_to` seja uma chave estrangeira pois conteria chaves primarias de duas tabelas distintas, há como contornar?

Comment: Não optando por isto :) Na verdade é possível dependendo de como faz sua aplicação. Chave estrangeria não é algo tão rígido assim se você não quiser por regra no banco de dados. Mas você só achou mais um motivo para não escolher esta opção. Faça o simples e óbvio. Eu dei como alternativa, não como a melhor alternativa.

Comment: Optando pela opção simples como eu saberia quais comentários meus ainda não foram respondidos? (a 1ª solução que imaginei é muito onerosa pois teria de ficar fazendo buscas em todo BD)

Comment: Aí você já está colocando novos requisitos. Provavelmente terá que fazer *sub-query*, mas não pensei muito sobre isto. Mas de qualquer forma modelagem não deve procurar em um primeiro momento a otimização de performance, ela deve prover as informações necessárias para resolver o problema. Se a estrutura física vai ter que ser adaptada para melhorar performance é um segundo passo que deve ser feito quando se mediu necessário. Em geral um índice vai resolver a questão, se houver lentidão.